# Transparent object on transparent background

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, transparency

I am using **Cycles Render** and **v2.79**. I have an object that is **partly transparent** and when I set the background to transparent (check transparent under Film) the **object has no alpha** and is rendered with the background (which is white). The rest of the background is transparent and edges that touch the background have variable transparency.

[image]

The two circled objects have the same material which is just a principled shader...

[image]

Why does this happen and what should I do to fix it? How to do I get the object to render with alpha?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2.80 or a recent daily build of 2.79 from builder bot:  https://builder.blender.org

Here in the film section you can find additional Transparent Glass option:

[image]

But if you don't need refraction, you can try Transparent shader instead of Principled transmission.

Or even in recent builds you can use Alpha value in Principled BSDF:

[image]